# Is the graph considered as overfit?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a training dataset of 2000 images and 500 images for validation. I have executed 50 epochs, however I realized that my graph seems to be different as my accuracy is smaller than my loss. I am not sure on whether my graph is considered as overfitting. If it is, are there other ways to resolve it? I am currently running on Jupiter notebook. Attached below is my code

**Edit:**

By the way, I have made some changes to my code, such as reducing the dropout to 0.2. I have uploaded the new graph output as shown below. Is it considered as normal?

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
import os
import cv2

Training_dir = './datasets/train'

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range =15, 
                         width_shift_range = 0.2, 
                         height_shift_range = 0.2,
                         rescale=1./255, 
                         shear_range=0.2, 
                         zoom_range=0.2, 
                         horizontal_flip = True, 
                         fill_mode = 'nearest', 
                         data_format='channels_last', 
                         brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5])

train_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    Training_dir,
    batch_size = 64,
    class_mode='binary',
    target_size=(150, 150)
)

Validation_dir = './datasets/val'

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range =15, 
                         width_shift_range = 0.2, 
                         height_shift_range = 0.2,  
                         rescale=1./255, 
                         shear_range=0.2, 
                         zoom_range=0.2, 
                         horizontal_flip = True, 
                         fill_mode = 'nearest', 
                         data_format='channels_last', 
                         brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5])


validation_gen = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    Validation_dir,
    batch_size = 64,
    class_mode = 'binary',
    target_size = (150, 150)
)

imgs = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\IM4483 Mini Project (Tang Soon Loong Jefferson_U1921181B)\datasets\train\cat")
imgs1 = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\IM4483 Mini Project (Tang Soon Loong Jefferson_U1921181B)\datasets\train\dog")
imgs2 = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\IM4483 Mini Project (Tang Soon Loong Jefferson_U1921181B)\datasets\val\dog")
imgs3 = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\IM4483 Mini Project (Tang Soon Loong Jefferson_U1921181B)\datasets\val\cat")
        
    

for img in imgs:
    img=cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\IM4483 Mini Project (Tang Soon Loong Jefferson_U1921181B)\datasets\train\cat" + "\\"+img)
    x = img_to_array(img)
    x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape) 

    i = 0
    for batch in train_datagen.flow (x, batch_size=1, save_to_dir =r'C:\Users\User\Documents\IM4483 Mini Project (Tang Soon Loong Jefferson_U1921181B)\Preview\train\cat', save_prefix ='cat', save_format='jpg'):
        i+=1
        if i>5:
            break

for img in imgs1:
    img=cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\IM4483 Mini Project (Tang Soon Loong Jefferson_U1921181B)\datasets\train\dog" + "\\"+img)
    x = img_to_array(img)
    x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape) 

    i = 0
    for batch in train_datagen.flow (x, batch_size=1, save_to_dir =r'C:\Users\User\Documents\IM4483 Mini Project (Tang Soon Loong Jefferson_U1921181B)\Preview\train\dog', save_prefix ='dog', save_format='jpg'):
        i+=1
        if i>5:
            break
            
for img in imgs2:
    img=cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\IM4483 Mini Project (Tang Soon Loong Jefferson_U1921181B)\datasets\val\dog" + "\\"+img)
    x = img_to_array(img)
    x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape) 

    i = 0
    for batch in val_datagen.flow (x, batch_size=1, save_to_dir =r'C:\Users\User\Documents\IM4483 Mini Project (Tang Soon Loong Jefferson_U1921181B)\Preview\Validation\dog', save_prefix ='dog', save_format='jpg'):
        i+=1
        if i>5:
            break
            
for img in imgs3:
    img=cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\IM4483 Mini Project (Tang Soon Loong Jefferson_U1921181B)\datasets\val\cat" + "\\"+img)
    x = img_to_array(img)
    x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape) 

    i = 0
    for batch in val_datagen.flow (x, batch_size=1, save_to_dir =r'C:\Users\User\Documents\IM4483 Mini Project (Tang Soon Loong Jefferson_U1921181B)\Preview\Validation\cat', save_prefix ='cat', save_format='jpg'):
        i+=1
        if i>5:
            break



from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, MaxPool2D, Flatten, Dropout

'''
SRC : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/31/keras-conv2d-and-convolutional-layers/
----------------------------------
STRIDES = The stridesparameter is a 2-tuple of integers, specifying the “step” of the 
convolution along the x and y axis of the input volume.
PADDING = Typically, we set the values of the extra pixels to zero 'valid' or 'same'
KERNEL_INITIALIZER = The kernel_initializercontrols the initialization method used to initialize
all values in the Conv2D class prior to actually training the network.

FLATTEN = Return a copy of the array collapsed into one dimension.
DROPOUT = dropout refers to ignoring units (i.e. neurons) during the training 
phase of certain set of neurons which is chosen at random. When created, the dropout rate can be specified to the 
layer as the probability of setting each input to the layer to zero. TO PREVENT OVER-FITTING.!

DENSE = A Dense layer feeds all outputs from the previous layer
to all its neurons, each neuron providing one output to the next layer. 
----------------------------------
'''




model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal',input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))


import tensorflow as tf
check_point_path = './best.h6'
model_checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath = check_point_path,
    monitor = 'val_accuracy',
    save_weights_only=False,
    save_best_only=True,
    verbose=1
)

model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0005,decay=1e-5),
             loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
             metrics = ['acc'])


tb_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/", histogram_freq=1)




print('Num Params : ',model.count_params())


'''
VERBOSE = By setting verbose 0, 1 or 2 you just say how do you want to 'see' the training progress for each epoch.
'''
model_history = model.fit(
    train_gen,
    epochs=50,
    batch_size=128,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks = [tb_callback],
    validation_data=validation_gen
)









%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.image  as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#-----------------------------------------------------------
# Retrieve a list of list results on training and test data
# sets for each training epoch
#-----------------------------------------------------------
Acc=model_history.history['acc']
Val_acc=model_history.history['val_acc']
Loss=model_history.history['loss']
Val_loss=model_history.history['val_loss']

epochs=range(len(Acc)) # Get number of epochs

#------------------------------------------------
# Plot training and validation accuracy per epoch
#------------------------------------------------
plt.plot(epochs, Acc, 'r')
plt.plot(epochs, Val_acc, 'b')
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend(["Training Accuracy","Validation Accuracy"])
plt.show()

#------------------------------------------------
# Plot training and validation loss per epoch
#------------------------------------------------
plt.plot(epochs, Loss, 'r')
plt.plot(epochs, Val_loss, 'b')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend(["Training Loss","Validation Loss"])
plt.show()
```

**Epochs output**

```
Num Params :  3273585
Epoch 1/50
32/32 [==============================] - 97s 3s/step - loss: 0.7618 - acc: 0.4925 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 2/50
32/32 [==============================] - 70s 2s/step - loss: 0.6916 - acc: 0.5330 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/50
32/32 [==============================] - 71s 2s/step - loss: 0.6946 - acc: 0.5250 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 4/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6911 - acc: 0.5205 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 5/50
32/32 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.6949 - acc: 0.5095 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 6/50
32/32 [==============================] - 74s 2s/step - loss: 0.6933 - acc: 0.5170 - val_loss: 0.6933 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 7/50
32/32 [==============================] - 74s 2s/step - loss: 0.6926 - acc: 0.5190 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 8/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6936 - acc: 0.5055 - val_loss: 0.6933 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 9/50
32/32 [==============================] - 74s 2s/step - loss: 0.6940 - acc: 0.5120 - val_loss: 0.6933 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 10/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5265 - val_loss: 0.6935 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 11/50
32/32 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.6929 - acc: 0.4975 - val_loss: 0.6934 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 12/50
32/32 [==============================] - 92s 3s/step - loss: 0.6935 - acc: 0.5035 - val_loss: 0.6933 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 13/50
32/32 [==============================] - 89s 3s/step - loss: 0.6924 - acc: 0.5115 - val_loss: 0.6935 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 14/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6929 - acc: 0.5095 - val_loss: 0.6935 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 15/50
32/32 [==============================] - 71s 2s/step - loss: 0.6928 - acc: 0.5175 - val_loss: 0.6940 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 16/50
32/32 [==============================] - 71s 2s/step - loss: 0.6916 - acc: 0.5170 - val_loss: 0.6941 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 17/50
32/32 [==============================] - 71s 2s/step - loss: 0.6922 - acc: 0.5205 - val_loss: 0.6945 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 18/50
32/32 [==============================] - 71s 2s/step - loss: 0.6894 - acc: 0.5280 - val_loss: 0.6949 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 19/50
32/32 [==============================] - 71s 2s/step - loss: 0.6887 - acc: 0.5205 - val_loss: 0.6956 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 20/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6870 - acc: 0.5400 - val_loss: 0.6963 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 21/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6864 - acc: 0.5380 - val_loss: 0.6974 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 22/50
32/32 [==============================] - 74s 2s/step - loss: 0.6836 - acc: 0.5505 - val_loss: 0.6965 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 23/50
32/32 [==============================] - 74s 2s/step - loss: 0.6722 - acc: 0.5640 - val_loss: 0.6903 - val_acc: 0.5280
Epoch 24/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6712 - acc: 0.5755 - val_loss: 0.6980 - val_acc: 0.5100
Epoch 25/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6709 - acc: 0.5735 - val_loss: 0.6946 - val_acc: 0.5180
Epoch 26/50
32/32 [==============================] - 74s 2s/step - loss: 0.6687 - acc: 0.5890 - val_loss: 0.7016 - val_acc: 0.5120
Epoch 27/50
32/32 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.6626 - acc: 0.5825 - val_loss: 0.7043 - val_acc: 0.5060
Epoch 28/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6675 - acc: 0.5830 - val_loss: 0.7053 - val_acc: 0.5060
Epoch 29/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6580 - acc: 0.5895 - val_loss: 0.7074 - val_acc: 0.5100
Epoch 30/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6632 - acc: 0.5875 - val_loss: 0.7036 - val_acc: 0.5200
Epoch 31/50
32/32 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.6705 - acc: 0.5685 - val_loss: 0.6877 - val_acc: 0.5400
Epoch 32/50
32/32 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.6595 - acc: 0.5880 - val_loss: 0.6821 - val_acc: 0.5520
Epoch 33/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6751 - acc: 0.5600 - val_loss: 0.7052 - val_acc: 0.5020
Epoch 34/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6536 - acc: 0.6015 - val_loss: 0.6853 - val_acc: 0.5580
Epoch 35/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6549 - acc: 0.6010 - val_loss: 0.6675 - val_acc: 0.5860
Epoch 36/50
32/32 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.6530 - acc: 0.6050 - val_loss: 0.7023 - val_acc: 0.5160
Epoch 37/50
32/32 [==============================] - 75s 2s/step - loss: 0.6559 - acc: 0.5910 - val_loss: 0.6965 - val_acc: 0.5380
Epoch 38/50
32/32 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.6423 - acc: 0.6225 - val_loss: 0.6719 - val_acc: 0.5920
Epoch 39/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6426 - acc: 0.6135 - val_loss: 0.7164 - val_acc: 0.5260
Epoch 40/50
32/32 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.6430 - acc: 0.6080 - val_loss: 0.6936 - val_acc: 0.5640
Epoch 41/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6440 - acc: 0.5980 - val_loss: 0.6894 - val_acc: 0.5720
Epoch 42/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6431 - acc: 0.6135 - val_loss: 0.7083 - val_acc: 0.5560
Epoch 43/50
32/32 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.6344 - acc: 0.6205 - val_loss: 0.6800 - val_acc: 0.5860
Epoch 44/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6687 - acc: 0.5735 - val_loss: 0.6699 - val_acc: 0.5940
Epoch 45/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6344 - acc: 0.6190 - val_loss: 0.7070 - val_acc: 0.5620
Epoch 46/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6340 - acc: 0.6160 - val_loss: 0.7012 - val_acc: 0.5740
Epoch 47/50
32/32 [==============================] - 74s 2s/step - loss: 0.6424 - acc: 0.5985 - val_loss: 0.7255 - val_acc: 0.5340
Epoch 48/50
32/32 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.6449 - acc: 0.5985 - val_loss: 0.7120 - val_acc: 0.5420
Epoch 49/50
32/32 [==============================] - 72s 2s/step - loss: 0.6437 - acc: 0.6120 - val_loss: 0.6708 - val_acc: 0.6140
Epoch 50/50
32/32 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.6497 - acc: 0.6030 - val_loss: 0.7339 - val_acc: 0.5280
```

**Graph output**

[image]

Comment: It's hard to say with that kind of variance. Main issue seems to be high learning rate. You'd better reduce the learning rate (or just use Adam) as the model converges.

Comment: Hi, my apologies I forgot to include my full code. I have just made changes to it. At that time, I have included the adam optimizer, but the graph still remains the same

Comment: "*my accuracy is smaller than my loss*" this is like comparing apples to oranges, and not an issue. Overfitting occurs when your training loss continuous to decrease while your validation loss start increasing; nothing of the sort happens here (there is no *trend* in the graphs), so this is not overfitting.

Comment: @desertnaut I see, thanks alot

Comment: What is the difference between underfitting and overfitting?

Comment: @Joseph See these slides: https://www.deeplearningbook.org/slides/05_ml.pdf